# How can i auto-locate places in the same page in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

very new to html!
So i see this feature in some of the websites and i like it when you tap the nav bar, it automatically goes to  that title in the homepage.

For example
If i tap , Packages,
the nav bar will automatically show the user Packages. not on a different page but on the same page.

How can i do that?

heres an example.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <style>

   </style>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <title>Food Box</title>
   
 </head>
 
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food Box<div class="logo-image" >
           <img src="" width ="46" height="46" class="img-fluid">
     </div>
   
</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
     <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home
           <span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span>
         </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Packages</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Service and Products</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
       </li>
       
     </ul>
     
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<header id="head">
           <img src="FoodBoxHome2.jpg" class="d-block" alt="intro" style="width:100% ">
       
   </header>
   
   <div class="container text-center">
       <br></br>
       <h2 class="thin">Packages</h2>
       <br></br>
       <p class="text-muted">
   
       </p>
   </div>
   
   <div class="container text-center">
       <br></br>
       <h2 class="thin">Service and Products</h2>
       <br></br>
       <p class="text-muted">
   
       </p>
   </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: These are called anchors. You can find information [here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-an-anchor-link-to-jump-to-a-specific-part-of-a-page.html)

Comment: You've described one of the uses of the Anchor tag. You can find "in-page" reference example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to anchors. you should add IDs to those div, and add `herf="#id"` to those nav bar tab.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <style>

   </style>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <title>Food Box</title>
   
 </head>
 
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food Box<div class="logo-image" >
           <img src="" width ="46" height="46" class="img-fluid">
     </div>
   
</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
     <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home
           <span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span>
         </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#packages">Packages</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#service-and-products">Service and Products</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
       </li>
       
     </ul>
     
   </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<header id="head">
           <img src="FoodBoxHome2.jpg" class="d-block" alt="intro" style="width:100% ">
       
   </header>
   —
   <div id="packages" class="container text-center">
       <br></br>
       <h2 class="thin">Packages</h2>
       <br></br>
       <p class="text-muted">
   
       </p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="service-and-products" class="container text-center">
       <br></br>
       <h2 class="thin">Service and Products</h2>
       <br></br>
       <p class="text-muted">
   
       </p>
   </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```